# Turning an abelian group into a topological group via neighbourhood bases.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am learning about topological groups and would be really grateful if someone could check that my proof below is correct. I have begun by recalling the relevant definitions. Many thanks!

---

Let $G$ be an abelian (additive) group and let $\mathcal{V}$ be a neighbourhood base for $0$ in $G.$

This means that $\mathcal{V}$ is a non-empty collection of subsets of $G$ such that

1) $0 \in V$ for all $V \in \mathcal{V},$

2) $\forall V_1,V_2 \in \mathcal{V} \; \; \exists V_3 \in \mathcal{V} \; : \; V_3\subseteq V_1\cap V_2,$

3) $\forall V \in \mathcal{V} \; \; \exists O \subseteq V \; : \; 0 \in O \; \text{ and } \; \forall x \in O \; \; \exists W \in \mathcal{V} \; : \; x+W\subseteq O.$

Then there is a unique topology on $G$ such that the neighbourhood system at $x \in G$ is given by
$$\mathcal{N}(x)=\{x+N \; : \; N\subseteq G \text{ where } N\supseteq V \text{ for some } V \in \mathcal{V}\}.$$

Assume now that for each $V \in \mathcal{V}$ there exist $V_1,V_2 \in \mathcal{V}$ such that
$$(*) \; \; \; \; \; (v_1 \in V_1 \; \text{ and } \; v_2 \in V_2)\Rightarrow v_1-v_2 \in V.$$

I wish to prove that the topology on $G$ is compatible with the group stucture.

**Proof:** We must prove that the map $f:G\times G \to G$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$
is a continuous.

Let $(x,y) \in G \times G$ be given.

Take any neighbourhood $(x-y)+N$ of $f(x,y)$ in $G.$

Let $V \in \mathcal{V}$ be such that $V \subseteq N$ and let $V_1,V_2 \in \mathcal{V}$ be such that $(*)$ holds.

Consider the neighbourhood $\Sigma=(x+V_1)\times(y+V_2)$ of $(x,y)$ in $G\times G.$

Then for any $(u,v) \in \Sigma$ we have  $u=x+v_1$ and $v=y+v_2$ for some $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2.$

Hence $f(u,v)=u-v=(x-y)+(v_1-v_2) \in (x-y)+V \subseteq (x-y)+N.$

This proves continuity of $f. \; \; \; $ Q.E.D

Comment: Yes, the argument is correct.

Comment: Many thanks! :)